# Paperclip isn't saving file in time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, elasticsearch, tire

I dont know what I did or what's changed because this was working before.

I have a Model `Entry` and I use Paperclip to attach a file `document` to it. Now, for some weird reason I keep getting a

```
Errno::ENOENT in EntriesController#create
No such file or directory - /var/www/capsf-web/public/assets/entries/test.pdf
```

I'm guessing that before Paperclip has saved the file to the directory I'm already trying to encode the file. Here's what `Entry` looks like. I'm using ElasticSearch's attachment mapper which is why I Encode it.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories
  belongs_to :entry_type
  has_attached_file :document,
                    :url  => "/assets/entries/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/entries/:basename.:extension"

  before_post_process :image?

  validates_presence_of :entry_type

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :url, :category_ids, :subcategory_ids, :entry_type_id, :document

  mapping do
    indexes :title
    indexes :description
    indexes :categories do
      indexes :name
    end
    indexes :subcategories do
      indexes :name
    end
    indexes :entry_type
    indexes :document, :type => 'attachment'
  end

  def to_indexed_json
   #to_json( methods: [:category_name, :subcategory_name, :entry_type_name])
    {
    :title          => title,
    :description    => description,
    :categories     => categories.map { |c| { :name => c.name}},
    :subcategories  => subcategories.map { |s| { :name => s.name}},
    :entry_type     => entry_type_name,
    :document       => attachment
    }.to_json
  end
  def image?
    !(document_content_type =~ /^image.*/).nil?
  end

  def attachment
    if document.present?
      path_to_document = Rails.public_path+"/assets/entries/#{document_file_name}"
      Base64.encode64(open(path_to_document) { |pdf| pdf.read})
#If I comment out the line above everything works just fine.

    end
  end


end
```

Comment: I installed CarrierWave to see if that would do the same thing and it didn't. So changing the gem has fixed my problem but I still haven't figured out why Paperclip is not saving the file.

 Does anyone know if there is any other type of processing done asynchronously? That might be stopping Paperclip from saving the file before I try to access it for encoding?

Comment: Cross-post from https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/502